# Magento show stock levels in Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid

Tags: magento

I want to show the stock level at order creation (in backend) during product selection stage in the search grid (Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid):
[image]

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 steps.

**First:** Find this file:

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php

And copy it to:

> app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php

This will help to make sure that you're not overwriting core files and instead creating local versions that won't get affected by upgrades.

**Second:** In the new file, the _prepareCollection() function will have code like:

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection
        ->setStore($this->getStore())
        ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array_keys(
            Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/sales/order/create/available_product_types')->asArray()
        ))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('gift_message_available');
```

Add this code to that block:

```
        ->joinField('qty2',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty','product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.stock_id=1','left')
```

So that the finished version looks something like:

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection
        ->setStore($this->getStore())
        ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
        ->joinField('qty2',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty','product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.stock_id=1','left')
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array_keys(
            Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/sales/order/create/available_product_types')->asArray()
        ))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('gift_message_available');
```

**Third:** Still in the new file, find the _prepareColumns() function and add this code:

```
    $this->addColumn('qty2', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Stock Level'),
        'width'     => '20',
        'type'      => 'number',
        'index'     => 'qty2'
    ));
```

Where you add the above code block into the _prepareColumns() function will determine the order of where the "Stock Level" column will display on the grid.

That's it.